# What is the "DanTherm" model in the SOATherm library in LTSpice?

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, thermal, modeling

LTSpice's SOATherm symbol has a "user-defined" option in the models list but I can't find any documentation on how to use it.  Out of curiosity I opened the .lib file and there is a user-defined model listed with the following parameters:

```
.subckt UserDefined D G S D2 G2 S2 Tj Tc

* The following two lines are customized for each DanTherm model * 
.param Tambient=85 RthetaJA=50 Cheatsink=0 
.param Imult=0 Iexponent=0 R6=0 C6=0 R5=0 C5=0 R4=0 C4=0 R3=0 C3=0 R2=0 C2=0 R1=0 C1=0
```

It seems I could define these values using a .param statement in my simulation - problem is I have no idea what the "DanTherm" model is.

So far Google has found what seems to be an HVAC brand by this name, but nothing about thermal modelling.  Is anyone familiar with this model?

Comment: I don't know the maning of `DanTherm`, but maybe it's related to the name of the one that wrote articles about SOAtherm, Dan Eddleman: [one](https://www.analog.com/cn/technical-articles/ltspice-modeling-safe-operating-area-behavior-of-n-channel-mosfets.html), [two](https://www.analog.com/cn/technical-articles/ltspice-soatherm-support-for-pcb-and-heat-sink-thermal-models.html). Also a [tutorial](https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/videos/5579253728001.html).

Comment: I find it odd that they provided a "user-defined" option for what seems to be a proprietary model. But maybe this is a question to pose to ADI.